# Warning: exec() [function.exec]: Cannot execute a blank command in

Tags: php, gnuplot

I am trying to plot a sine graph using GNUPLOT in PHP, but when I use `exec` to plot the graph I get this error:

> Warning: exec() [function.exec]: Cannot execute a blank command in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/serverSide2.php on line 8

here is my code:

```
exec(`echo "set term png;set xrange[-2*pi:2*pi]; set output 'output.png'; plot sin(x)" | gnuplot`);
```

I used passthru() also but got the same error: 
Warning: passthru() [function.passthru]: Cannot execute a blank command in /Library/WebServer/Documents/serverSide2.php on line 8

However I used the terminal to check whether the code is working or not, so I entered this code: 
`echo "set term png;set xrange[-2*pi:2*pi]; set output 'output.png'; plot sin(x)" | gnuplot`
and it worked properly and gave me the plot.

any I idea what should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax.

**Either** use `exec` and write the command line as a string literal:

```
exec('echo "set term png;set xrange[-2*pi:2*pi]; set output \'output.png\'; plot sin(x)" | gnuplot');
```

**or** use [backticks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) and do *not* involve `exec` at all:

```
`echo "set term png;set xrange[-2*pi:2*pi]; set output 'output.png'; plot sin(x)" | gnuplot`;
```

With the code you already have, the backticks cause the command to be executed and its *output* to be passed to `exec`. Since this command line produces no output, `exec` then complains that it cannot execute a blank command.

Comment: Now it does not give error anymore, but it doesn't save the output.png after I run the php file : localhost/server.php

Comment: @Emad: Did you use the backtick version? I just noticed I had left in a couple of extra backslashes when copy-pasting from the `exec` version.

Comment: I used both versions, even the corrected backtick version but still the output does not save anywhere. (It suppose to be saved in localhost folder but it doesn't)

Comment: @Emad: Did you manage to resolve this? Did the command line need adjustment?

Comment: Yeah I had to give permissions to apache user in order to save file in localhost folder.

Answer (score 3):

Using both `exec` and the backtick operator is redundant -- basically, they both do the same. The backtick operator actually executes it's contents as a shell command and returns the output of the command. So you actually call `exec` with an empty string, if your command does not output anything.